# Is there any way to scroll the div with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with css `overfow:hidden`. But I need scrolling in this `div`. I googled it and find the solution is to change the `overflow:scroll` and hide the scrollbar. But in macbook pro, I am able to see the scrollbar. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
<style type="text/css">
    .inside { width: 500px; overflow: auto; height: 200px; padding-right: 20px; }
    .outside { width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden; }
</style>

<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam pretium enim blandit ligula pharetra pharetra. Curabitur posuere nibh at nibh tincidunt sed porta dui commodo. Suspendisse id vulputate magna. Cras non arcu ac lacus dignissim pretium. Aenean varius luctus ante, sed tincidunt neque euismod id. Sed aliquam dui eu purus dapibus venenatis. Praesent tortor sem, pretium in rhoncus eu, eleifend at lectus. Donec dignissim turpis et lectus interdum dignissim. Maecenas porttitor ante ut ligula tempus sit amet tincidunt arcu aliquam. Vivamus at velit massa. Nulla eget ligula sed dolor porta porta sit amet ac est. Vestibulum rhoncus tempus ligula quis vulputate. Nullam auctor, neque tristique ultrices iaculis, neque nisl semper est, id adipiscing ligula est eu diam.</p>

            <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec enim ante, rhoncus at egestas eget, imperdiet vitae sem. Mauris sed massa elit, ac posuere nibh. Integer ut metus et felis blandit pellentesque id eget velit. Quisque vehicula consectetur nibh sit amet posuere. Etiam egestas lacus id justo fringilla sodales. Donec scelerisque aliquam urna sed sodales. Cras ornare neque fringilla nisl molestie venenatis. Quisque quis lacus ut augue sodales tristique non id sapien. Sed risus nisl, egestas eu sodales ut, rhoncus id nisl. Maecenas hendrerit tellus neque. Aliquam sodales gravida luctus. Suspendisse porta porta libero at venenatis. Proin laoreet accumsan ipsum, et ultrices nisi pharetra et. Nullam in dolor quam, et adipiscing ipsum. In consequat interdum sollicitudin. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Youtube solves this through toggling between `overflow-y: hidden; padding-right: 17px` and `overflow-y: scroll; padding-right: 0;` through `:hover`.

It makes it look neat, and it lets the user know that you *can* scroll. Consider to tell your users that, instead of asuming that they know it.

Answer (score 1):

Try `overflow: auto;` This will show the scroll bar if it is needed, ie the height of the content in the div is larger than the height of the div. Otherwise if the content fits within the bounds of the div, it will not show a scroll bar.

Answer (score -1):

[you can use the jquery scrolltop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)